# iOS - Reasons for app crashing besides low memory?

Tags: ios, memory-management, crash, crash-reports

Trying to figure out why my app crashes sometimes. I just ran it in Leaks, and it crashed even though Live Bytes was only 3.09 MB. So it doesn't appear that I'm using too much memory. There are no errors logged to the console when the crash occurs when running on the device through Xcode. Also there are no crash logs on the device.

What else can I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: Where does the debugger stops, when it crashes?

Comment: your question is too generic to be answered in a specific way. Try to cut down to your specific error and console message on crash.

Comment: Maybe your app segfaults. Or randomly gets killed by the OS.

Comment: it could be bad memory access I guess. Try NSZombies on Simulator

Answer (score 1):

There could be multitude of reasons for Application Crash. Here are a few most common ones.

- Bad Memory Access.

  Occurs when you access an over released memory object. To solve, use NSZombies using the Simulator. Sometimes crashes are not simulated in simulator, in those cases, you are on your own.
- Invalid Argument Exception

  Usually occurs if you access a property or invoke method call on an object that it does not have. Commonly due to invalid casting of objects for example casting `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray` from `id` type and trying to add object to it.

  Solution is to debug using breakpoints and see what is the actual class of the object using following command and cast the object to appropriate type.

  ```
  po [object class]
  ```
- `UIViewController`s issues

  Creating a view controller with xib file that does not exist.

  Creating a view controller with view outlet not set in IB.

  Setting IBOutlet of a `UIControl` like `UITextField` in `File Owner` and then accidentally removing it from `File Owner` and not resetting in XIB file.

And plenty more .. !!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Will try the Zombies. The other two don't seem like the problem, because it crashes at random times. It's not something I can reproduce by following certain steps.